# How to Convert this WIF 3.5 code to WIF 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wif

I have this code sample from WIF 3.5 that I haven't yet been successful in converting to WIF 4.5.

1. The ClaimsCollection is gone in 4.5
2. There is ambiguity between System.IdentityModel.Claims.Claim and System.Security.Claims.Claim. Not sure which one is the equivalent of the Claims in the original code.
3. I've been trying ClaimsIdentity instead of ClaimsCollection, but the claims in a ClaimsIdentity object do not have an enumerator. This is probably an obvious indication that ClaimsIdentity is not the proper type to use here, but I haven't found the right one yet.

Here is the code:

```
ClaimCollection claims = ((IClaimsIdentity) HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Claims;    
IEnumerable<Claim> claimQuery = from c in claims
     where
     c.Type ==
     "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"
select c;
```

Comment: Have `var` in both lines and `ClaimsIdentity` in place of `IClaimsIdentity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cp = HttpContext.Current.User as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = cp.FindAll("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn");
```